# Powerpoint Slide Libraries in Sharepoint 2013 missing "copy slides to presentation" on webparts

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, slidelibrary, powerpoint

If someone could help with this it would be a great help.

So - I am aware that SP2013 has removed PowerPoint Slide Libraries but have found (on here) a way to add them back in and as a Content Part they work just fine.

However, when added as a Webpart the "Copy slides to presentation" button disappears and renders the whole concept useless!

I have found a link to a blog post explaining how to rebuild this functionality but for the life of me can not make it work.

http://sureshannamalai.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/copy-slides-to-presentation-outside-of.html

Any pointers or help much appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Make a Page viewer web part

In that webpart on your page - Insert the link of the Slide Library and after the URL insert `?IsDlg=1` (example: `URL.aspx?IsDlg=1`) Put this customized URL in a Page viewer web part.

It should work just fine.